# How to visualize (and not pick) image from the Camera Roll

Tags: iphone

I will like to visualize the images from the Camera roll from my application. Something like with the Album app which let you zoom and pan pictures. I tried using the UIImagePickerController with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum as sourceType but unfortunatly if a tap a picture, the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called with the picture selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the image picker is currently the best you can get. If you want zoom and panning you’ll have to write the code yourself (using the `UIImage` returned from the image picker).